# Is there an option to show website title instead of url in ionic inappbrowser?

Tags: ionic-framework, inappbrowser

$window.open(encodeURI(ENV.liveSite), '_blank', 'location=yes,clearcache=yes,clearsessioncache=yes,hideurlbar=yes,toolbarcolor=#e85147');

Answer (score 1):

There is another plugin available for this that is Theme `ThemeableBrowser`

```
Func(){
const options: ThemeableBrowserOptions = {
     statusbar: {
         color: '#ffffffff'
     },
     toolbar: {
         height: 44,
         color: '#f0f0f0ff'
     },
     title: {
         color: '#003264ff',
         showPageTitle: true
     }
    }
    const browser: ThemeableBrowserObject = this.themeableBrowser.create('https://ionic.io', '_blank', options);
  }
```

[reference](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/themeable-browser)

Comment: Your answer is very helpful but please let me know how can I use it in ionic version 1, not typescript.